# KnpMenu, unable to set current menu item

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, knpmenu

I have seen the other errors about this problem. I have done the exact same thing. When I try to render the menu I get this Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Knp\Menu\MenuItem::setCurrentUri()
in ProjectBundle/Menu/Builder.php on line 23
```

This is how my Builder looks:

```
<?php
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{

private $factory;

public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

public function createMenu(Request $request)
{

    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->setCurrentUri($request->getRequestUri());

    $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => '_home'));
    $menu->addChild('About', array('route' => '_about'));
    $menu->addChild('Bullshit', array('route' => '_bullshit'));

    return $menu;
}
}
```

I went through the issue tracker on Github, and it seems this issue has been fixed, but why do I have the same issue again?

I mean, when I `var_dump($menu)`, it clearly says it's a `MenuItem` and seeing the Documentation of KnpMenu, there is definitely a `setCurrentUri()` method for my `$menu`.

Comment: Maybe you are using and old version of the bundle? Are you running Symfony 2.0 or 2.1? Take a look at your deps or composer.json file to see if you are asking for a specific version

Comment: Or the other way around: are you using the latest version of the bundle but an outdated documentation?

Comment: The documentation is from their Github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `MenuItem::setCurrentUri()` method was deprecated as of v1.1.0. See https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/issues/63 for more information. That issue has several links on how to set the current uri of the menu using `UrlVoter` instead.

Comment: You were right, I haven't been able to find that out myself. I read on a couple of answer on SO that `setCurrentUri()` should work. I did a RequestVoter and implemented VoterInterface. It works now. See [this fix on Github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/122#issuecomment-6563863)

Answer (score 3):

It should doesn't work if the probleme is due to the request
. You can try that:

```
 public function **CreateMenu**(\Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
{   $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

    $menu->setCurrentUri($this->container->get('request')->getRequestUri());
$menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => '_home'));
$menu->addChild('About', array('route' => '_about'));
..

return $menu;}
```

Answer (score 3):

@aurny2420289 gives a simple solution.

But now it's suggested to use a UriVoter

```php
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\UriVoter;
use Knp\Menu\Renderer\ListRenderer;

//...

$matcher = new Matcher();
$matcher->addVoter(new UriVoter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

$renderer = new ListRenderer($matcher);

//...
```

Comment: API is so developer-friendly

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution.
just add:

```
$menu->setCurrent(true);
```

It adds class 'current' to current menu. Method `setCurrentUri` has been deprecated and later removed from knpmenu.